# Combine root path with several child paths

Tags: powershell

How can I combine several paths, for ex.: **file1**, **file2**, **file3** with root **C:**?

I know that possible this:

```
Join-Path C:\, D:\, E:\ file
```

Output:

```
C:\file
D:\file
E:\file
```

I need conversely, something like:

```
Join-Path C:\ file1, file2, file3
```

And output:

```
C:\file1
C:\file2
C:\file3
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"file1","file2","file3" | %{ Join-Path c:\ $_ }

c:\file1
c:\file2
c:\file3
```